# Counting problem involving permutations - verification please?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

I have tried solving this, but I'm unsure if I'm right. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Question: 15 kids arrive at camp and are assigned a place to sleep. There are 3 different cabins each of which can hold 5 kids. How many ways are there to assign kids to cabins?

My answer: (15,5) (meaning 15 choose 5) *3 
I did it this way because i believe u need to first find out the number of possible ways make groups of 5 from 15 kids and then multiply that number with 3 (because of 3 cabins)

Answer (score 1):

You are not right.

From the group of 15, you can put 5 kids in the first cabin $C(15,5)$ ways.
For the second cabin, you can choose 5 kids $C(10,5)$ ways (since 5 kids are in the cabin already). The last cabin must have the remaining 5 kids, so 1 way.

Thus, it is $C(15,5) * C(10,5) * 1$.